# How to extract date from a filename using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have to handle a long filename in a specific format that contains two dates and someone's full name. Here is a template that describes this format:

`firstname_middlename_lastname_yyyy-mm-dd_text1_text2_yyyy-mm-dd.xls`

How to extract the fullname, first date, and second date from that filename using regular expression?

I've tried to extract the first date like:

```
string1 = 'CHEN_MOU_MOU_1999-04-11_Scientific_Report_2020-03-14.xlsx'
ptn = re.compile('\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\b')
print(ptn.match(string1))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The output I get is `None`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _But it seems doesn’t work._ Can you be more specific? What happens, and which part are you struggling with?

Comment: All answers are wrong, just use word boundaries that "exclude" underscores, `ptn = re.compile(r'(?<![^\W_](\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?![^\W_])')`

Comment: Thanks ALL, it helps me out there. @WiktorStribiżew I'm interested in the reg you provide, but I got a list with blank values as ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''......], anything wrong with ptn = re.compile(r'(?<![^\W_](\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?![^\W_]))')

Comment: No idea, you must be doing something wrong. [It works with `re.findall`](https://ideone.com/qNkDpT). I don't  understand why you accepted an answer telling you to remove word boundaries. You still do not want to match `1111-11-11` in `Abc1111-11-11_2020-03-15.xls`, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. Actually I want to match "firstname_middle_lastname" and "1111-11-11" and "2020-03-15" in "firstname_middlename_lastname_1111-11-11_2020-03-15.xls".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your solution does not work is because `_` is considered an alphanumeric character in Python.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters):

> `\w`
>   Matches any alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

So `\b` does not match `_` in your string. But it'll match `-`.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters):

> `\b`
>   This is a zero-width assertion that matches only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric character.

But if you replace `_` around your dates with a `-` (hyphen), then your solution works just fine.

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = 'CHEN_MOU_MOU-1999-04-11-Scientific Report-2020-03-14.xlsx'
>>> ptn = re.compile(r'\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\b')
>>> ptn.findall(string1)
['1999-04-11', '2020-03-14']
```

Following is a solution that should work for your task:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> string1 = 'CHEN_MOU_MOU_1999-04-11_Scientific_Report_2020-03-14.xlsx'
>>> fullnamepattern = r'[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+'
>>> datepattern = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
>>> re.search(fullnamepattern, string1).group()
'CHEN_MOU_MOU'
>>> re.findall(datepattern, string1)
['1999-04-11', '2020-03-14']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to extract all dates with the format `yyyy-mm-dd` in the string :

```
string1 = 'CHEN_MOU_MOU_1999-04-11_Scientific_Report_2020-03-14.xlsx'
ptn = re.compile("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
all_dates = ptn.findall(string1)
# ['1999-04-11', '2020-03-14']

full_name = " ".join(string1.split('_')[:3])
# 'CHEN MOU MOU'
```

Comment: I think you are missing the fullname `How to extract the fullname, first date, and second date`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract dates using reguler expression but you can extract full name easily using split function ***try following code to get more idea***

```
string1 = 'CHEN_MOU_MOU_1999-04-11_Scientific_Report_2020-03-14.xlsx'
pattern = re.compile("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
dates=pattern.findall(string1) # it will return first date and last date in dates's array


fullname = string1.split("_") # split data using _ character and it stored in array
fullname = " ".join(fullname[:3]) #join with fullname blank space (first three data)
```

Or  you can join last **two** line in one

```
fullname = " ".join(string1.split("_")[:3])
```

Please let me know what you think about it

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(.*?)_(?=\d)(.*?)_(.*)_(.*?)\.(.*)$')

string = 'CHEN_MOU_MOU_1999-04-11_Scientific_Report_2020-03-14.xlsx'

split_filename = pattern.findall(string)
split_filename
```

Output:

```
[('CHEN_MOU_MOU', '1999-04-11', 'Scientific_Report', '2020-03-14', 'xlsx')]
```

Running...

```
split_filename[0][3]
```

shows...

```
'2020-03-14'
```

At least this way you can pick what you would like to read/check/record. Just change the [3] above to another number to get a different part...

```
split_filename[0][0]
'CHEN_MOU_MOU'
split_filename[0][4]
'xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
\d[^_\.]+
```

- `\d` match a digit
- `[^_\.]+` match all except "." or "_"

[image: enter code here]